# Converting Canvas element to Image and storing in database

Tags: html, servlets, canvas

I want to store the Image into my Server side Database. Once the user draw using canvas and hit a <kbd>Submit</kbd> button , **Canvas Element should be converted to image format** and then I want to store that Image into my database for further use. I can use this image to verify the user next time he visits my site.

Can anyone help me to sort it out? My server code is written in **Java Servlets**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Canvas.toDataURL()` which will return a string with a base64 encoded PNG. You can then store it as a normal text or decode and save as a file. To put it back on canvas you simply pass this string as a source for `Canvas.draw(source, 0, 0) method`

Fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/9a7Xd/