# Is possible extract data:image of canvas element?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, base64

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting Canvas element to Image and storing in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493947/converting-canvas-element-to-image-and-storing-in-database)

I have a  canvas element and i want the "data:image/png;base64" of this element. Is possible extract this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [the toDataURL function of Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975241%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It makes exactly what you ask for.

```
var dataURLstring = canvas.toDataURL();
```

MDN documentation : [HTML Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement)

> Returns a data: URL containing a representation of the image in the
>   format specified by type (defaults to PNG).